# Free metadata file information tool for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, metadata

Does anyone know any free alternatives to [Informator](http://www.end-if.de/E/Products/Informator/InformatorPro.html)?

[image]

As a sidenote, this doesn't deal with EXIF metadata only. I'm hoping for video, music, and who knows what else beside images **metadata**. Being able to view and edit as well.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 16):

If you're not afraid of using the Terminal:

```
mdls /path/to/file
```

Comment: +1; you (probably) do not need any more than this

Comment: That's great, but I couldn't find how to edit the metadata with it, which is what I wanted. It seems it's not possible. And I still hope for a GUI. :)

Comment: mdls is read-only. xattr can write the data

Comment: How do I see FPS using that?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there do not see to be any tools which let you edit the Apple metadata beyond the standards created for digital images like EXIF, which I understand you aren't concerned about.

You can achieve the **writing** of metadata elements such as `kMDItemWhereFroms` in the Terminal using the `xattr` command.
`mdls` is for reading the metadata only.

Example for writing the file's origin:

```
xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms 'http://www.example.com' <filename>
```

See [more here](http://hmmaha.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/add-where-from-to-firefox-downloads-mac-os-x/)

Comment: ¡I think You Can, I think I just figured it out!   It's listed in the developer's tools, although you still might be able to do it if you haven't downloaded them.  If you have, check out: /Developer/Tools/SetFile
If not, here's a manual page: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/SetFile.1.html

From what I understand, xattr changes extended metadata (extra stuff I guess?) while SetFile will change things like creation date, last opened, all those.  Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it's something!

Comment: @Frost Shadow. We are trying to change the extended metadata. SetFile won't change kMD metadata. Cheers for the info though